# Using msiexec to uninstall programs

Tags: windows, batch-file, uninstall, windows-installer

I have found a batch file that removes a lot of bloatware etc.

Example:

```
start /wait MsiExec.exe /I{DB731A07-34DE-4BE0-AE94-45C83E28A56C} /quiet
```

I guess the `{DB731A07-34DE-4BE0-AE94-45C83E28A56C}` is the program.
If I have more programs to add to the batch, how can I find this key for them?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933

Comment: Please note that this command only applies to programs using Windows Installer. It’s entirely possible (and likely!) for unwanted software to use another installer or even roll their own.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all products and their corresponding Product IDs with the following command:

`wmic product get name, IdentifyingNumber`

It may take a couple minutes to run and gather the info depending on how many programs you have installed. Once complete, it will output a list like:

```
{789A5B64-9DD9-4BA5-915A-F0FC0A1B7BFE}  Java Auto Updater
{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F03217071FF}  MSXML 4.0 SP2
{46F044A5-CE8B-4196-984E-5BD6525E361D}  Apple Software Update
{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AB0000000001}  Adobe Reader XI (11.0.10)
etc...
etc...
```

You can then run the following command to uninstall. Just replace the product key in the example with the product you want to uninstall:

`msiexec /x {123A4B56-7CD8-9EF0-123G-H4IJ5K6L7MN8} /q`

Answer (score 0):

You could try Rob van der Woude's [GetUninstall.bat](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=getuninstall_w7) or [GetUninstall.vbs](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/getunins_vbs.txt).

For the batch file, just provide part of the program name thusly `getuninstall.bat chrome` (no quotes, from a command line), and it will find matching entries, plus provide the uninstall string if applicable.

For the VBScript, it's slightly different, but results are the same: `cscript getuninstall.bat /f:"chrome"`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I see in batch: only for win7. does it work in win8?

Comment: @StianStørstfeskarAndersen: Should work. The check is for a "Windows_NT" based OS, which should work. But I can't test as I currently don't have a Win 8.x based system handy. Try it. If not, try the VBScript version.